# Car.class - is "class" a variable?

Tags: java

`Class c1 = Car.class;` What is this `.class` ? Is it a public variable which exists in every class ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.class` syntax is the same as the syntax for accessing static fields, but it isn't actually a static field; it's a special language feature. It's similar to an array's `length` property, which is accessed as if it were a field but not actually stored as one.

To see the difference, consider this example class:

```
class Test {
  public static Class<Test> myClass = Test.class;
}
```

Running `javap Test` gives

```
class Test {
  public static java.lang.Class<Test> myClass;
  Test();
  static {};
}
```

As you can see, `Test.myClass` is stored as a static field since we declared it ourselves, but `Test.class` does not show up since it is not actually stored as a static field.

Answer (score 4):

It's special syntax for getting the corresponding `Class` object. `class` is a keyword so no, there's no property called "class", it's just a syntactical shortcut that resembles property access. It's like

```
Class.forName("Car")
```

except it doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: So, its only made to save our time and confuse us in the process ? :)

Comment: @davidblaine No, that's faster than looking up a class by its name.

Comment: `Class.forName("Car")` is a runtime method call where `Class<Car>` is a compile-time type.  The former will compile even if no class named `Car` exists where the latter needs an `import` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Every Object in Java belongs to a certain class. That's why the Object class, which is inherited by all other classes, defines the getClass() method.

`getClass()`, or the class-literal - `Foo.class` return a Class object, which contains some metadata about the class:

- name
- package
- methods
- fields
- constructors
- annotations

and some useful methods like casting and various checks (isAbstract(), isPrimitive(), etc). the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) shows exactly what information you can obtain about a class.

It points to the instance of `Class` from a class name. If you have an object of the same class, you can also use

```
Class c1 = Class.forName("Car");
```